# Selecting amongst several values per item with Semantic-UI search dropdown

Tags: html, jekyll, semantic-ui

I use [Semantic-ui dropdown search](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#search-selection) feature.

Using this, I want to search amongst events who have several speakers by name of one of the speakers.

I use Jekyll to populate my dropdown. The Jekyll code is as follows:

```
 {% for event in site.events %}
    <div class="item" data-text="{% for speaker in event.people %}{{ speaker.name }} {% endfor %}">
            <h3 class="ui header"> {{ event.header }}</h3>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which compiles into several blocks like this:

```
<div class="item" data-value="Bob Charles Jack Bill" >
    <h3 class="ui header">The opening speech</h3>
</div>
```

I want to be able to filter these events based on any of the names of the people mentioned in the `data-text` attributes.

For now, it only returns a match if I type the first of the names in my `data-text` attribute i.e. "Bob" in this case. Is there an option I don't know about to achieve that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the `fullTextSearch` option for the dropdown, but I assumed it was either true or false (none doing what I want).

It turns out that you can set `fullTextSearch` to "exact" to achieve what I wanted.